# Python pandas : How to create a list by matching element in one column another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, linked-list

A dataframe with :

```
     Locations      Locations 
        1              2
        1              3
        2              7
        2              8
        7              11
```

The locations are in pairs, for example ,birds in location 1 will fly to 2, but they can also fly to 3. Then in location 2 they will fly to location 7, then 11.

I want to create lists where i can chain the pairs together, having no repeated elements, in a effective way.

expected sample output:

```
     [1,2,7,11]
     [1,3]
     [2,8]
```

Comment: Look at `networkx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to using`DiGraph` from `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='Locations',
                                   target='Locations.1',edge_attr=True,
                                   create_using=nx.DiGraph())
roots = list(v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0)
leaves = list(v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0)

[nx.shortest_path(G, x, y) for y in leaves for x in roots]

Out[58]: [[1, 3], [1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 7, 11]]
```

Comment: Nice answer @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary of lists to represent the graph

```
g = {}
for _, l0, l1 in df.itertuples():
    g.setdefault(l0, []).append(l1)

print(g)

{1: [2, 3], 2: [7, 8], 7: [11]}
```

Then define a recursive function to traverse the graph

```
def paths(graph, nodes, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    for node in nodes:
        new_path = path + [node]
        if node not in graph:
            yield new_path
        else:
            yield from paths(graph, graph[node], new_path)

roots = g.keys() - set().union(*g.values())

p = [*paths(g, roots)]
print(*p, sep='\n')

[1, 2, 7, 11]
[1, 2, 8]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

so i found this way to address your problem without any graphs involved.
But you will have to use a copy of your dataframe if you want to use it afterwards.
And your data has to be ordered like it is in your example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["loc1","Loc2"],data=[[1,2],[1,3],[2,7],[2,8],[7,11]])

res = []
n = -1
m = -1
x = 0
for i in df.values:
    if(x in df.index): ###  test wether i has already been deleted
        res.append(i.tolist()) ### saving the value

        m = m +1  ###        m is for later use as index of res
        tmp = i[1]
        for j in df.values:
            n = n +1       ### n is the index of the df rows
            if(j[0] == tmp):
                res[m].append(j[1])
                df = df.drop(df.index[n])   ### deleting the row from which the value was taken
                tmp = res[m][len(res[m])-1]
                n = n -1

        n = -1
    x = x+1
print(res)

[[1, 2, 7, 11], [1, 3], [2, 8]]
```

I know it is not the best looking but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you asked for, but this question would fit well into a graph using Networkx. You can search for all simple paths between each node (location) within a directed graph defined by your dataframe:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combination

# Create graph from dataframe of pairs (edges)
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(df.values)

# Find paths
paths = []
for pair in combinations(G.nodes(), 2):
    paths.extend(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=pair[0], target=pair[1]))
    paths.extend(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=pair[1], target=pair[0]))
```

`paths`:

```
[[1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 2, 7],
 [1, 2, 8],
 [1, 2, 7, 11],
 [2, 7],
 [2, 8],
 [2, 7, 11],
 [7, 11]]
```